# NSManagedObject Custom Accessor Method

Tags: sorting, nsfetchedresultscontroller, nsmanagedobject

I hope someone can give me some helpful suggestions on what to do about this.

I have been trying several ways to sort a set of entities that have the relationship **client<-->>job** based on a custom accessor for a property of client as the first sort descriptor, and then the job description property as the second sort descriptor.

I first tried to use a transient property, called Client.sortValue, and discovered that transient properties can't be used as sort descriptors with the NSFetchedResultsController. So I changed the property Client.sortValue to be non-transient.

I never save a value for sortValue to the persistent store. Instead, I use a custom accessor. Apparently, the custom accessor method is not being used when the **fetechedResultsController performFetch:** method is run. It is called when I do logging, as shown in the code below. I can see that this is the case using a break point in the custom accessor and viewing the stack trace. I don't see it break on the accessor method when the performFetch is run, but it does break on the accessor method when the logging is done.

(Strangely, I had it working earlier today under some circumstances, but not others. It was obviously being sorted the way I wanted it to be, but after I refactored my code to track down the conditions where it worked, I have not seen it work again.)

I have tried various custom accessor methods, including the following:

```
- (NSString *) primitiveSortValue {

    NSString *retVal = nil;

    [self willAccessValueForKey:@"lastName"];
    [self willAccessValueForKey:@"firstName"];
    [self willAccessValueForKey:@"company"];

    if (![self.lastName isNullString] ) retVal = [self primitiveValueForKey:@"lastName"]; 
    else if (![self.firstName isNullString] ) retVal = [self primitiveValueForKey:@"firstName"]; 
    else if (![self.company isNullString] ) retVal = [self primitiveValueForKey:@"company"]; 
    else retVal = @"";

    [self didAccessValueForKey:@"lastName"];
    [self didAccessValueForKey:@"firstName"];
    [self didAccessValueForKey:@"company"];


    NSLog(@"Sort Value: %@", retVal);

    return retVal;
}
```

I also tried this one before deciding to override the primitive accessor method:

```
- (NSString *) sortValue {

    NSString *retVal = nil;

    if (![self.lastName isNullString] ) retVal = self.lastName; 
    else if (![self.firstName isNullString] ) retVal = self.firstName; 
    else if (![self.company isNullString] ) retVal = self.company; 
    else retVal = @"";


    NSLog(@"Sort Value: %@", retVal);

    return retVal;
}
```

Here is my fetchedResultsController method:

```
#define CLIENT_SORT_KEY @"clientOfJob.sortValue"
- (NSFetchedResultsController *) fetchedResultsController {
    if (fetchedResultsController != nil) {
        return fetchedResultsController;
    }

    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    NSEntityDescription * entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Job" inManagedObjectContext:dataInterface.managedObjectContext];

    [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];

    [fetchRequest setFetchBatchSize:10];

    if (segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex == 0) {  // sort by client, then job dscription
        NSSortDescriptor *clientSortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:CLIENT_SORT_KEY ascending:YES];
        NSSortDescriptor *jobSortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"jobDescription" ascending:YES];

        NSArray *sortDescriptors = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:clientSortDescriptor, jobSortDescriptor, nil];
        [fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:sortDescriptors];

        NSFetchedResultsController *aFetchedResultsController = 
        [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] 
         initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest 
         managedObjectContext:dataInterface.managedObjectContext 
         sectionNameKeyPath:CLIENT_SORT_KEY
         cacheName:nil]; 


        aFetchedResultsController.delegate = self;

        self.fetchedResultsController = aFetchedResultsController;

        [aFetchedResultsController release];
        [fetchRequest release];
        [jobSortDescriptor release];
        [clientSortDescriptor release];
        [sortDescriptors release];        
    }
    else { // sort by job description
        ...        }

    NSError *error = nil;

    if (![fetchedResultsController performFetch:&error]) {
        NSLog(@"Unresolved Error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
        abort();
    } 

    int i = 0;
    for (id<NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo> sectionItem in [fetchedResultsController sections]){
        NSLog(@"\n***********\nsection %d name %@\n-----------\n",i++, [sectionItem name]);
        int j = 0;
        for (Job *jobItem in [sectionItem objects]) {
            NSLog(@"%d job: %@, client: %@\n",j, jobItem.jobDescription, jobItem.clientOfJob.sortValue);
        }
    }

    return fetchedResultsController;

}
```

Comment: Since it seems like client-job relationship is a one-to-many, have you tried doing the custom accessor on the job entity and have it either use the client object directly or have lastName, firstName, etc. just copied straight to your job object? From my experience, adding an relational complexity to FRC code barely ever works.  I'm also trying to solve a custom accessor sort problem, so please update if you figured out a solution.